# Enhancing a simple 2D graphics

Tags: plotting

This is a nice plot of an economic problem

```
   g1 = ContourPlot[ x^.5 y^.5, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, Ticks -> False, 
   ContourStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed}}, 
   Contours -> {{.266, Directive[Green, Thickness[.005]]}, ## & @@ 
      Range[0.325/2, 1., .3]}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ContourShading -> {{Opacity[0.1], RGBColor[0, 0, 0]}, {Opacity[.1],
       RGBColor[0, 0, 0]}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], 
     Style["y", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]}, ImagePadding -> 40,
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontWeight -> Plain, 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}];
g2 = ContourPlot[.2 x + .4 y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Axes -> True, Ticks -> False, 
   ContourStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}}, 
   Contours -> {{.149, Directive[Orange, Thickness[.005]]}}, 
   Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ContourShading -> {{Opacity[.01], 
      RGBColor[0.1, 0, 0.1]}, {Opacity[.01], RGBColor[0.1, 0, 0]}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], 
     Style["y", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]}, ImagePadding -> 40,
    PlotRangePadding -> 2, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontWeight -> Plain, 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"},
   Epilog -> {Text[
      Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(\[Star]\)]\) ", 
       FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {.5, -.1}]}
   ];
g3 = Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{0, 0.185}, {.38, 0.185}, {.38, 0}}]}];
g4 = Graphics[{Red, Scale[Disk[{.38, 0.185}], .01]}];
t1 = Graphics[{{Text[
      "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U\), \(\[Star]\)]\) ", {.9, .1}]}, \
{Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\[Star]\)]\) ", {.4, .22}]}, \
{Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(\[Star]\)]\) ", 
       FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {.4, -.03}]}, {Text[
      Style["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(R\), SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]]\)", 
       FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
       FontSize -> 7], {.75, -.06}]}}, {Text[
     Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(\[Star]\)]\) ", 
      FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {-.3, .5}]}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}];
Show[g1, g2, g3, g4, t1, AxesStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[.03]], 
 ImagePadding -> 30, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

which gives

[image]

Now with the help of kglr I can add some comments under the x axis. But I do not know how to include some text befor the y-axis

Comment: For the Arrows I just have found that to add to Show AxesStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[.03]] make the buzz

Comment: What would you like to do? Do you mean, you want to add some text into the above graphics as means of annotation? :s I would suggest to edit the question to outline the main objectives of what you are willing to achieve

Comment: does `Show[g1, g2, g3, g4, t1,  PlotRangeClipping -> False]` work for you?

Comment: Kglr It works partially. Ihave changed the code and graphic of the question. Obviously, I have do not see the $Y*$

Comment: Kglr Thanks. Now it works perfectly. In my last change I have made a false position of a curly bracket. After removing the error all is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using `SciDraw`. In my opinion, it is easier and in particular much more organized / cleaner code if you want to get fancy figures. Here is how I would apply it to your code:

```
Quiet[Needs["SciDraw`"]];
SetOptions[FigObject, FontSize -> 12, FontSlant -> Italic];
Figure[
 FigurePanel[
  {
   FigGraphics[g1];
   FigGraphics[g2];
   FigGraphics[g3];
   FigGraphics[g4];
   FigLabel[{.9, .1}, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U\), \(\[Star]\)]\) "];
   FigLabel[{0.4, 0.22}, 
    "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\[Star]\)]\) "];
   },
  XPlotRange -> {0, 1},
  YPlotRange -> {0, 1},
  XTicks -> {
    {0.4, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(\[Star]\)]\) "},
    {0.75, 
     Style["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(R\), SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]]\)", 
      FontSize -> 7]}
    },
  YTicks -> {
    {0.5, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(\[Star]\)]\) "}
    }
  ],
 CanvasSize -> {3, 4}
 ]
```

Note how options can be set globally so you don't need to repeat that for every item. Also note how you can "recycle" your old graphics g1-g4.

Admittedly, I haven't found an option to use draw the Axes instead of a Frame.  However, in worst case, just draw the frame with 0% opacity and manually draw two arrows with `FigArrow`.

[image]

Update:

Here is the code including the arrows instead of a frame:

```
Quiet[Needs["SciDraw`"]];
SetOptions[FigObject, FontSize -> 12, FontSlant -> Italic];
SetOptions[FigArrow, ArrowType -> Block, Width -> 1];
Figure[FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[g1];
   FigGraphics[g2];
   FigGraphics[g3];
   FigGraphics[g4];
   FigLabel[{.9, .1}, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U\), \(\[Star]\)]\) "];
   FigLabel[{0.4, 0.22}, 
    "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\[Star]\)]\) "];
   FigLabel[{0.4, -.05}, 
    "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(\[Star]\)]\) "];
   FigLabel[{0.75, -.1}, 
    "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(R\), SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]]\)", 
    FontSize -> 7];
   FigLabel[{-.05, 0.5}, 
    "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(\[Star]\)]\) "];
   FigLabel[{1.05, 0}, "x"];
   FigLabel[{0, 1.05}, "y"];
   FigArrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}];
   FigArrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}];
   },
  XPlotRange -> {-.1, 1.1},
  YPlotRange -> {-.2, 1.1},
  Frame -> False
  ],
 CanvasMargin -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 CanvasSize -> {5, 6}]
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: A simpler draw. Until now I have not used Scidraw since I have not been able to implant it. After what you have shown I will retry. Thanks